# How to get list width by width all inside elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, width, push

Have this problem: i need to get list width by all of inside elements. So, i try to get each elements width and connect them in one peace. But now i have only one element width... Can u help me?

```
var list_width = [];
$('#js_films_block_top li').each(function() {
    list_width.push($(this).width());
});
console.log(list_width);
```

Thx for help.

Comment: how many elements with the id=js_films_block_top do you have? if it's more than one, it's a very bad practice

Comment: What is `#js_films_block_top`? Is it the list and why it is iterating through single unique id element how is that possible? Your concept is messed up in the first place.

Comment: Again, is it `lis_width` or `list_width` (Notice the `t` in `list`)? Please provide accurate information

Comment: I don't see any flaws your last modification should work if the HTML markup  is fine

Comment: i'v add li selector after id of list

Comment: I still don't get your question at all. Please put a fiddle together

Comment: The problem isn't in the code provided. If the selector is fine and if there are `li` DOM elements the code should work. What are the values in the printed array, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i have good solution for this:

```
$('#js_films_block_top').each(function(){
    var t = $(this),
        tW = 0;
    $('li', t).each(function(){
        tW += $(this).outerWidth(true) + 5;
    });
    t.css('width', tW + t.outerWidth(true) - t.width());
});
```

thx, anyway.